# Is it possible to access an online MySQL database in Access 2013?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have an online MySQL database that I use for the backend to my website. However to get to the database, I have to login to my hosting provider, then log in to cPanel, and then log into phpMyAdmin, which is quite slow to use.

I would like to be able to access or stream the database to Access so I could download, edit and upload sections of it. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like it, see [this news item](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-odbc/en/news-5-2-5.html). [Here is the search I used](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=access+2013+mysql+connector) to find that information. Is there an ODBC configuration dialogue in Access 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, nothing forbid you to make some linked tables in Access toward an online MySQL database using the Mysql ODBC driver.  However, for security purpose, most hosting services will block anything that is not a direct HTML access to a web site at their firewall level.  Therefore, you have to ask your provider if such an access is allowed and if yes, what are the connection parameters.